# Pandas slicing by element in cell

Tags: python, pandas, slice

What is the best way to slice by looking for a single element within a cell? I know how to do it with the .isin() function where the cell element is in a list. But I am actually looking for the reverse:

```
id       vals
1        ['wow', 'very', 'such']
2        ['wow', 'such']
3        ['very', 'such']
```

I wanted something like this (but this doesn't work):

```
df['very' in df['vals']]

id       vals
1        ['wow', 'very', 'such']
3        ['very', 'such']
```

I think an alternative is to use apply(), matching on the value, but it seems a little inelegant.

Comment: Do you want to match a string containing `delivery` (where `very` is a sub-string)?

Answer (score 2):

A `list-comprehension` to select rows which contain only the string *very* could be used:

```
df[['very' in x for x in df['vals'].values]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
df[df.vals.apply(lambda x: 'very' in x)]
Out[9]: 
                vals
0  [wow, very, such]
2       [very, such]
```

Comment: PS: all due respect to OP's edited comment, what is inelegant in pandas is likely storing list objects in a dataframe. An option to consider would be to split the lists into columns and work with that. In the meantime apply is not inelegant

Comment: thanks for your input. what if the list of possible words is in the 10,000s?

Comment: you have 10000s columns, what would be the issue with that?

Comment: I feel it would be more difficult to visually interpret with a sparse table like that

Comment: Not sure to see how it would be more difficult to visualize between a 10k horizontal list vs 10k columns horizontal scalars. But it's a choice you balance: you don't have scalar means you prevent your code from using all pandas features, thus you have to use apply.

Comment: sorry what i mean to say is that all possible words across all records could be in the 10's of thousands, but for each record there would probably be only 4 or 5 words that might be relevant.

Comment: Thus you have 4 or 5 columns. dito

Comment: ah i see what you are saying. i was thinking you meant that there would be a column 'wow' with a binary value for each record. what you are saying makes sense as well; however given that tables like this need to be interpreted by non-analysts i choose to make them as easy to visualize as possible. thanks again!